# how to compare two files and print mismatched line number in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-comparison

I have two files which contains same number of lines.

```
"file1.txt" contains following lines:

 Attitude is a little thing that makes a big difference
 The only disability in life is a bad attitude
 Abundance is, in large part, an attitude
 Smile when it hurts most

"file2.txt" contains:

 Attitude is a little thing that makes a big difference
 Everyone has his burden. What counts is how you carry it
 Abundance is, in large part, an attitude
 A positive attitude may not solve all your problems
```

I want to compare two files line by line and if any of the line mismatches between two files i want to

```
 print "mismatch in line no: 2"
 print "mismatch in line no: 4"   #in this case lineno: 2 and lineno: 4 varies from second file
```

I tried.but i can print only the line in file1 which is differ from line in file2.can't able to print the line number of mismatched lines.??

```
 My code:
 with open("file1.txt") as f1:
    lineset = set(f1)
 with open("file2.txt") as f2:
    lineset.difference_update(f2)
    for line in lineset:
        print line
```

Comment: Why are you making it a set? Do you want to erase duplicates?

Comment: no i dnt want to erase that line.i want to print the line no of file1 which mismatch the file2 lines.in my case line 2 and line 4 differs from file2.so i want to print mismatch in line2 and 4

Comment: Have you heard of `diff`?  This is kinda reinventing the wheel ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) and [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
import itertools

with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2:
    for lineno, (line1, line2) in enumerate(itertools.izip(f1, f2), 1):
        if line1 != line2:
            print 'mismatch in line no:', lineno
```

Comment: For python 3, use "zip" instead of "itertools.izip" and print('mismatch in line no:', lineno)

Answer (score 2):

What if:

```
with open("file1.txt") as f1:
    with open("file2.txt") as f2:
        for idx, (lineA, lineB) in enumerate(zip(f1, f2)):
            if lineA != lineB:
                print 'mismatch in line no: {0}'.format(idx)
```

Or if there are a different number of rows you can try [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

```
import itertools

with open("file1.txt") as f1:
    with open("file2.txt") as f2:
        for idx, (lineA, lineB) in enumerate(itertools.izip_longest(f1, f2)):
            if lineA != lineB:
                print 'mismatch in line no: {0}'.format(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the `difflib` module. Here's a simple example using its [`difflib.Differ`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#differ-objects) class:

```
import difflib
import sys

with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
    line_formatter = '{:3d}  {}'.format
    file1_lines = [line_formatter(i, line) for i, line in enumerate(file1, 1)]
    file2_lines = [line_formatter(i, line) for i, line in enumerate(file2, 1)]
    results = difflib.Differ().compare(file1_lines, file2_lines)
    sys.stdout.writelines(results)
```

Output:

```
    1  Attitude is a little thing that makes a big difference
-   2  The only disability in life is a bad attitude
+   2  Everyone has his burden. What counts is how you carry it
    3  Abundance is, in large part, an attitude
-   4  Smile when it hurts most
+   4  A positive attitude may not solve all your problems
```

The minus and plus characters in the first column indicate lines that were replaced in typical `diff` utility program style. The absence of any indicator means the line was the same in both files -- you could suppress the printing of those if you wished, but to keep the example simple everything the `compare()` method creates is being printed.

For reference, here's the contents of the two files side-by-side with line numbers shown:

```
1  Attitude is a little thing that makes a big difference    Attitude is a little thing that makes a big difference
2  The only disability in life is a bad attitude             Everyone has his burden. What counts is how you carry it
3  Abundance is, in large part, an attitude                  Abundance is, in large part, an attitude
4  Smile when it hurts most                                  A positive attitude may not solve all your problems
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2:
    for lineno, (line1, line2) in enumerate(zip(f1, f2), 1):
        if line1 != line2:
            print ('mismatch in line no:', lineno)
```

Comment: Please format your code when answering, I corrected this time.

Comment: To make your answer be a good one, you should explain your code to the requester, so everyone can understand and learn, and not dump code. Thanks